# How to find the average of features matrix of cnn model in python

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, average

I have a video dataset where each video is represented by 20 frames as numpy file.
I want to extract video features by **averaging the feature vectors of these 20 frames**.
So, I have ( 20 CNN feature vectors ) of pre-trained EfficientNetB0 with shape of `(None,100,1280)`, each for one frame, where None is for batch and (100,1280) is the output feature of CNN model.

so I have:

```
feat_1 => (None,100,1280)
feat_2 => (None,100,1280)
.
.
.
feat_20 => (None,100,1280)
```

How to find `average_feat` with shape of (None,100,1280)